# Is there a way to limit the network bandwidth / filesystem use per user over NFS on a Solaris 10 file server?

Tags: networking, zfs, file-server, nfs, cisco-nexus

We have a large file server running on Solaris 10 and about 200 computing nodes running on Ubuntu. The nodes access the file server over NFS. The load gets larger and larger over time.

Is there a way to restrict the resources (either in/outbound network bandwidth or the I/O to/from the ZFS filesystem on the storage) on the per-user basis? If it's not possible on Solaris, can we tweak the network switch (Cisco Nexus 5k series) to achieve the same?

How do other people manage the access to a large single file system in a fair way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You can do this on the server in Crossbow using IPQoS to limit bandwidth in increments of 150KiB/s.
2. You can do this on the client using the Linux tc command:

---

**Sources**

1. http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23823_01/html/816-4554/ipqostm-1.html
2. http://lartc.org/manpages/tc.txt